# nil is not compatible with the expected argument type '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `XCode 7.2` and `Swift 2.2`. I have a function that accepts a `dictionary([NSObject : AnyObject])` as a parameter. However, I want to call this function without using that dictionary or in other words by making the parameter nil. If I do that, this is thrown:

> nil is not compatible with the expected argument type '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

My code is

```
self.silentPostData(
  persist.getObject(
    mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERNAMEKEY) as String, 
    serverport: persist.getObject(mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERPORTKEY) as String,
    serverurl:  mdmiosagent_Constants.NATIVE_APP_SERVLET,
    parameters: nil ,
    urldata: jsonData
  )
)
```

The parameter in conflict is named parameters in the code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the method expects a non-optional dictionary, pass an empty one.

Comment: add [NSObject : AnyObject]? to the parameter of your function

Comment: What class is `self`? Is this an external library, not an Apple one? Maybe format that long line into smaller lines.

Comment: same error @Ro22e0

Comment: self is a class inherited from NSObject

Comment: @vadian , the method expects a non-optional dictionary . but i don't know how exactly to pass an empty one

Comment: Try `[:]` or `[NSObject : AnyObject]()`

Comment: Ok but what class is it? And what class is `persist`? As others have said it probably comes down to using an empty `Dictionary` but by leaving out these details it makes diagnosing the more issue difficult.

Comment: well , that fixed it @ vadian

Comment: and if i have to make the parameter (which is NSData) as nil , would passing it as [] help ?

Comment: `[]` is the short form for an empty `Array`, empty NSData is `NSData()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only nullable types (such as optionals or types that conform to the protocol `NilLiteralConvertible`) can be `nil`, or compared to `nil`. Therefore, you have following options:

**1. Make the parameter optional**

convert the parameter of the function to `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`

**2. Pass an empty dictionary**

just call:

```
self.silentPostData(
  persist.getObject(
    mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERNAMEKEY) as String, 
    serverport: persist.getObject(mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERPORTKEY) as String,
    serverurl:  mdmiosagent_Constants.NATIVE_APP_SERVLET,
    parameters: [:],
    urldata: jsonData
  )
)
```

Comment: well, any type that conforms to `NilLiteralConvertible` can be `nil`, and if it's `Equatable` as well it can be compared to it. Of course the rest of the answer is flawless :)

Answer (score 7):

Just pass this `[:]` in your function so.

Comment: I tried it , but the same error was thrown as type [NSObject:AnyObject] cannot be used with array literal.

Comment: He probably means `[:]`

Comment: You have to do  [ : ] to get a `Dictionary`

Comment: Yes sorry ;) tanks @Eendje